# Is gravel under lower control arm joint a problem?

Tags: honda, suspension, control-arm, front-wheel-drive

2002 Odyssey, two images here of  lower control arm joints where it meets the body. One of the driver side which is cleaned out, and one of the passenger side showing a pebble in the same area.  The driver side was packed with something like 5 to 10 pebbles plus dust before cleaning.

I have been experiencing some odd noises (grinding, clanking, rubbing) from my front suspension, mostly from the driver side. I had an independent mechanic check out the suspension and he said everything is tight and looks good.

I still noticed various sounds on sharp right turns or bumps so I decided to pull off the front wheel and look for anything else that might be rubbing, and the main thing I noticed was a bunch of gravel under the lower control arm where it connects to the body.

I cleaned it out with some picks and a shop vac.

I'm wondering if there is any cause for concern in having gravel build up there, other than potentially being a source of some harmless but weird noises?

[image: passenger side joint, showing one rock, as an example]
[image: cleaned out (driver side) joint]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that can be a problem.  Clean it out.

The stones will interfere with the operation of the suspension components and could possibly accelerate wear and tear.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it probably wasn't good but I wasn't sure what the expected range of motion was in that area. Do you happen to know?   I'm guessing it pinches up and down over bumps, is there any rotation in that joint when steering?